# Is it possible to define macros in makefiles conditionally?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make, hp-ux

I'm writing a makefile that has to be compatible with both LINUX and the HP-UX operating system.  I'm aware that certain shell commands in LINUX are not compatible with HP-UX.  Consequently, I was wondering if it was possible to have macros declared conditionally so that if it was determined that the OS was HP-UX, the macro would be defined a certain way and if the OS was LINUX, it would be defined differently?

```
OS       = `uname`
myOS     = Linux


ifeq ($(OS),$(myOS))
    message = "HELLO LINUX"
else
    message = "HELLO FOO" 
endif

all: install

install:
    echo $(message)
```

I've tried using the approach above; however, it seems that ifeq determines that OS and myOS are not the same.  They should both be 'Linux', but it's outputting the else block instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall use $(shell ...) in order to execute a SHELL command, this will work

```
OS       := $(shell uname)
myOS     := Linux


ifeq ($(OS),$(myOS))
    message := "HELLO LINUX"
else
    message := "HELLO FOO" 
endif

all: install

install:
    echo $(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define [conditionals in makefiles](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/make/make_7.html).

This example taken from the above link

```
libs_for_gcc = -lgnu
normal_libs =

foo: $(objects)
ifeq ($(CC),gcc)
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(libs_for_gcc)
else
        $(CC) -o foo $(objects) $(normal_libs)
endif
```

This shows the [syntax for conditionals](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/make/make_7.html#SEC69).

Given this defining anything specific should not be a problem. E.g., one could define/pass on marcos via the `-D` switch for a C program.

**Update**: To fix your problem with the **OS** variable not getting the output of the shell command `uname` you need to use [shell function](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_8.html#SEC83) (as correctly pointed out by @AraundF): To quote from the link I posted:

> "The shell function performs the same function that backquotes (``)
>   perform in most shells ..."

so you were on the right track.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I shall give this a try.

Comment: I tried to define the following...however it doesn't seem to be working. OS       = `uname`
myOS     = Linux


ifeq ($(OS),$(myOS))
 message = "HELLO LINUX"
else
 message = "HELLO FOO"
endif

all: install

install:
 echo $(OS)
 echo $(myOS)
 echo $(message)

Comment: using the uname command, OS should be equal to 'Linux'...however, it's not picking up the equality. Instead, it thinks that OS and myOS are different.

Comment: @Justin can you update/edit your question and add this code to the bottom of it? It's hard to make out otherwise

Answer (score 0):

What we used to do here is we define an environment variable `ARCH` on all systems we build stuff on, on a Linux system it will have value `linux`, on AIX `aix`, etc., in the `Makefile` we have:

```
include make.$(ARCH)
```

and for each platform we create a file called `make.linux`, `make.aix`, etc., with definitions specific for that platform, for example `make.linux` contains:

CC=g++

and `make.aix` contains

CC=xlC_r

This is quite a nice and clean approach, but nevertheless we are migrating to cmake ( http://www.cmake.org/ ) now.